# Performance issue with JavaFX LineChart with 65000 data points

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

It takes JavaFX 15 minutes to build described LineChart which doesn't work for my task.

Similar implementation using good old Swing and jFreeChart takes 1.5 seconds to build chart.

But I would still like to implement a JavaFX one.

Here is my code:

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label statusbar;
@FXML
public LineChart lineChart;
@FXML
public Button connect;
@FXML
public MenuItem options;
@FXML
public NumberAxis xAxis;
@FXML
NumberAxis yAxis;

@FXML
private void connect(ActionEvent event) {

}
public static FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
public static String path;
public static XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer> dataSeries = new XYChart.Series<Integer, Integer>();
public static int y = 0;
public static XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer> data;


@FXML
private void open(ActionEvent event) {
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
            new ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"),
            new ExtensionFilter("Audio Files", "*.wav", "*.mp3", "*.aac"),
            new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
    if (selectedFile != null) {
        path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path);
        try {
            ReadingFromFile.readFile(path);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}

@FXML
private void close(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
private void getconnect(ActionEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    xAxis.setLabel("Tick");
    xAxis.setTickUnit(100);
    yAxis.setLabel("Signal");
    xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    lineChart.setLegendVisible(false);
    lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.getData().add(dataSeries);
  }
}
```

and reading from file:

```
public class ReadingFromFile extends FXMLController {

public static String s = null;
public static String[] str;
public static int parseInt;

public static void readFile(String filename)
        throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(line);
            try {
                str = line.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i = i + 2) {
                    s = str[i + 1] + str[i];
                    parseInt = Integer.parseInt(s, 16);
                    javafx.application.Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            data = new XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>(y, parseInt);
                            //data.setNode(new HoveredThresholdNode(0, second, ""));
                            dataSeries.getData().add(data);
                            y++;
                        }

                    });
                }
            } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException ex) {
                System.out.println("тут ноль!!!");

            }

        }

    } finally {

        br.close();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: First optimization would be to add all the data points to the series at one time. So create a `List<XYChart.Data<Integer, Integer>>`, add all the data points to that list in your loop, and then when you are done, just have a single `Platform.runLater(...)` with `dataSeries.getData().addAll(...)` and pass in the list. You still might not be able to make this work, though; the JavaFX Chart API is a highly visual component, with CSS applied to node(s) associated with every data point. It's not really designed for substantially more data than you can actually see.

Comment: @James_D ok it helped a little. Now 1 minute and 25 seconds. but it's still too long ((

Comment: Well, a 10-fold increase in performance on the first optimization is a pretty good start. You're probably more likely to get useful help here if you edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you probably need to create from scratch). You should be able to build an executable example with a  large `LineChart` with just a few dozen lines of code, at most.

Comment: I am having the same issues, trying to make a chart with thousands of data points. AddAll is much faster than adding them one at a time.

You might also want to try changing the tick mark units on the x axis. Try setting it to something really large so you only have 1 or 2 tick marks and see if performance improves by much. If it does then you can try to find a happy medium. My performance improved a lot doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem, adding 100,000 points to a LineChart every couple of seconds. We solved it using the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), this reduces the number of points in the line without the user noticing. I found an ready-made implementation in the [JTS topology suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm) under LGPL license.

Here's the my test code.

```
public class ChartUpdate extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 50_000, 5000);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-1, 1, 25);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        LineChart<Number, Number> graph = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        graph.setAnimated(false);
        graph.setCreateSymbols(false);
        graph.setLegendVisible(false);
        Series<Number, Number> series = new Series<>();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(graph));

        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

        long t0 = System.nanoTime();
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[100_000];
        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
            coordinates[i] = new Coordinate(i, Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i / 100)));
        }
        Geometry geom = new LineString(new CoordinateArraySequence(coordinates), gf);
        Geometry simplified = DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(geom, 0.00001);
        List<Data<Number, Number>> update = new ArrayList<Data<Number, Number>>();
        for (Coordinate each : simplified.getCoordinates()) {
            update.add(new Data<>(each.x, each.y));
        }
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println(String.format("Reduces points from %d to %d in %.1f ms", coordinates.length, update.size(),
                (t1 - t0) / 1e6));
        ObservableList<Data<Number, Number>> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(update);
        series.setData(list);
        graph.getData().add(series);

        stage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: The JTS topology suite link is dead. I did find a link here: https://locationtech.github.io/jts/ if it is the same. Not certain.

Answer (score 0):

Ramer-Douglas-Peucker is unnecessarily complicated, and even with a faster downsampling strategy, this alone is not enough to get the performance we need. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557072/1033706) for a more complete solution. This has achieved true real-time updating for me with data sets of 40,000 or so.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this problem too. Below is an example of the class with comments. I also create a JavaFX application to test the entered epsilon and number of markers on GitHub. [JavaFX Line Chart Example](https://github.com/walleyyang/line-chart-peuker-example)

```
/**
 * Uses the Douglas Peucker algorithm for reducing the series.
 * Reference: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_line_simplification#Java
 */
public class SeriesReducer {

  private double epsilon;

  /**
   * Filters the series. This assumes the data set is a map that uses the keys for a line chart
   * category axis and uses the values for a line chart number axis.
   * 
   * @param chartDataSet The map containing the chart data set
   */
  public Map<String, Integer> filter(Map<String, Integer> chartDataSet) {
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> dataSet = new ArrayList<>(chartDataSet.entrySet());
    List<Entry<String, Integer>> pointListOut = new ArrayList<>();
    reduce(dataSet, pointListOut);

    Map<String, Integer> reducedSeriesMap = new TreeMap<>();
    pointListOut.forEach(entry -> reducedSeriesMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    int pointListOutSize = pointListOut.size();
    String percentage =
        numberFormat.format((1 - ((double) pointListOutSize / (double) dataSet.size())) * 100);
    String reducedByMessage = pointListOutSize + " (" + percentage + "%)";
    AppViewModel.getInstance().setReducedByMessage((reducedByMessage));

    return reducedSeriesMap;
  }

  /**
   * Gets the perpendicular distance.
   * 
   * @param line The line object with the data
   * @return The perpendicular distance
   */
  private double getPerpendicularDistance(Line line) {
    double dx = line.getLineEndX() - line.getLineStartX();
    double dy = line.getLineEnd().getValue() - line.getLineStart().getValue();

    double mag = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
    if (mag > 0.0) {
        dx /= mag;
        dy /= mag;
    }
    double pvx = line.getPointX() - line.getLineStartX();
    double pvy = line.getPoint().getValue() - line.getLineStart().getValue();

    double pvdot = dx * pvx + dy * pvy;
    double ax = pvx - pvdot * dx;
    double ay = pvy - pvdot * dy;

    return Math.hypot(ax, ay);
  }

  /**
   * Reduces the number of points.
   */
  private void reduce(List<Entry<String, Integer>> pointList, List<Entry<String, Integer>> listOut) {
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = pointList.size() - 1;
    int index = 0;
    double maxDistance = 0;

    for (int i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
      Line line = new Line.Builder()
          .setPoint(pointList.get(i))
          .setLineStart(pointList.get(startIndex))
          .setLineEnd(pointList.get(endIndex))
          .setPointX(i)
          .setLineStartX(startIndex)
          .setLineEndX(endIndex)
          .build();

      double distance = getPerpendicularDistance(line);

      if (distance > maxDistance) {
        index = i;
        maxDistance = distance;
      }
    }

    if (maxDistance > epsilon) {
      List<Entry<String, Integer>> result1 = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Entry<String, Integer>> result2 = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Entry<String, Integer>> firstLine = pointList.subList(startIndex, index + 1);
      List<Entry<String, Integer>> lastLine = pointList.subList(index, pointList.size());
      reduce(firstLine, result1);
      reduce(lastLine, result2);

      List<Entry<String, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(result1.size() + result2.size());
      result.addAll(result1);
      result.addAll(result2);

      listOut.addAll(result1.subList(startIndex, result1.size() - 1));
      listOut.addAll(result2);
    } else {
      listOut.clear();
      listOut.add(pointList.get(startIndex));
      listOut.add(pointList.get(pointList.size() - 1));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sets the threshold epsilon.
   * 
   * @param epsilon The margin for the curve
   */
  public void setEpsilon(double epsilon) {
    this.epsilon = epsilon;
  }

}
```